# Duplicate Sample IDs/Outcomes and recode as unique and missing using R

Tags: r

I have a data set that consists of Sample IDs and a corresponding outcome variable. However, there are some duplicate Sample IDs in my data set. What I would like to do is identify the duplicate Sample ID and recode this Sample ID as a unique name and then recode the outcome variable as missing. I am aware that it would be easier to just remove the entire row but I need the maintain the number of rows.

So I have a data set like this:

```
dt<- data.frame(ID=c("A", "B", "A", "C"), Outcome=c("1", "1", "1", "1"))
```

And I would like to recode it so it looks like this:

```
dt1<- data.frame(ID=c("A", "B", "A.1", "C"), Outcome=c("1", "1", "-9", "1"))
```

Thanks!

Comment: What have you considered or tried, and what is the issue?

Answer (score 3):

The dataset columns were `factor` class.  I would use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in the `data.frame` call to create non-numeric columns with class 'character'.  The reason is that if we are going to change some values/replace some levels in 'factor' class, we need to have that new 'value' as one of the 'levels' of that 'factor'.  So to avoid that, I convert the already 'factor' columns to 'character'.  In the example, both columns are 'factor' class.  So we loop through the columns of 'dt' with `lapply` and change the columns to 'character' (`as.character`).

```
 dt[] <- lapply(dt, as.character)
```

I guess the OP wanted to have `unique` elements in the 'ID' column by replacing the `duplicate` IDs.  One option is `make.unique`.

```
 dt$ID <- make.unique(dt$ID)
```

After we convert the 'ID' to `unique` IDs, we can check for `.` in that column and replace the corresponding elements in the 'Outcome' column by -9.

```
 dt$Outcome[grep('[.]', dt$ID)] <- -9
 dt
 #   ID Outcome
 #1   A       1
 #2   B       1
 #3 A.1      -9
 #4   C       1
```

---

Or as @A.Webb mentioned in the comments, we can use `duplicated` with `ifelse` to change the 'Outcome' column values.

```
 transform(dt,
       ID=make.unique(as.character(ID)), #change the ID column
       Outcome=ifelse(duplicated(ID),-9, ​Outcome)) #change Outcome
```

Comment: The `grep` is dangerous if you already have legit dots in some of the names. Instead, use a `duplicated` check on the original. `transform(dt,ID=make.unique(as.character(ID)),Outcome=ifelse(duplicated(ID),-9,Outcome))`